# How do I get list of calendar app data?

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar, nsmutablearray, nsdate

**For example:**

I would like to access all my calendar data (default iOS App) which has user embedded data on
Start date 11/11/2013 10:00 AM with Title "Meeting w/ Australian".
Or another one,
Start date 1/1/2012 08:00 AM with Title "2012 New Year's Party".

How do I access these and put them on NSMutableArray?

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Given the quarantine-like protection built in IPhone apps, I bet you won't be able to access the info, I've never tried personally but I'm willing to bet on it.

thats probably why all the calendar apps start empty.

I would look at exporting Ical to CSV then parsing it ingot he app as a hacky way to get around it.

Good luck though.